# Change value of HTML attribute

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How do I change the value of an attribute of an HtmlDocument?

What I tried:

```
destinationFileDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(pathWithoutAttribute).Attributes[attributeName].Value = newValue;
```

Didn't work.

```
string OldValue = destinationFileDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(pathWithoutAttribute).Attributes[attributeName].Value;
destinationFileDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(pathWithoutAttribute).SetAttributeValue(attributeName, NewValue);
```

Didn't work either. I actually thought my first approach should work.

How can I change the value?

/edit: My second approach is wrong, first argument in SetAttribute should be the attribute name. Will try this rn.
/edit: still not working
/edit: https://html-agility-pack.net/set-attribute-value setAttributeValue doesnt seem to able to change a value if there is an exisiting one already.

/edit:

```
string result = null;
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    destinationFileDocument.Save(writer);
    result = writer.ToString();
}
HtmlDocument newDoc = new HtmlDocument();
newDoc.LoadHtml(result);
destinationFileDocument = newDoc;
```

Adding this to the second solution fixed it.

Comment: Why didn't it work? What issue are you encountering?

Comment: So this wasn't an issue with changing the attribute - you just hadn't initialized the document?

Comment: No that's not the issue. destinationFileDocument is the already initalized document. Hold on I'm trying to explan the problem.

Comment: The changes are performed. The value is actually updated if I watch it with the debugger. Now I want to write it to the old file but the old value is there. So apparently I need to explicitly save it?

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly save it. You're not modifying the file in place, you're modifying a `HtmlDocument` object in memory. See the following https://html-agility-pack.net/save